# Assist with implementing Radix Sort in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, radix

I need some help implementing the Radix sort algorthim in JavaScript.

I found [this example](http://www.coedu.usf.edu/wwwprog/sort_demo.html) online, with the following code, but I don't understand how I call the function since it appears to be tailored for that site:

```
// Radix sort a (base 2)
// Numbers must be in the range 0 to 2**31 - 1
function radixSort() {
  readArray('i');
  var b0 = new obj();  // Bin for 0 digits
  var b1 = new obj();  // Bin for 1 digits

  for (var i=0; i<32; ++i) {
    if (form.step.checked) {  // Single step
      writeArray('i','a');

      if (!confirm("Sort on bit "+i))
        return;    
    }

    var mask = 1<<i;     // Digit (2**i)
    var biggest = 2<<i;  // If all of a is smaller, we're done
    var zeros=0;         // Number of elements in b0, b1
    var ones=0;
    var found=false;     // Any digits past i?

    for (var j=0; j<n; ++j) { // Sort into bins b0, b1
      if ((a[j] & mask) == 0)
        b0[zeros++] = a[j];
      else
        b1[ones++] = a[j];

      if (a[j]>=biggest)  // Any more digits to sort on?
        found=true;
    }

    for (j=0; j<zeros; ++j)  // Concatenate b0, b1 back to a
      a[j]=b0[j];

    for (j=0; j<ones; ++j)
      a[j+zeros]=b1[j];

    form.imoves.value = parseInt(form.imoves.value)+n;

    if (!found)
      break;
  }

  writeArray('i','a');
}
```

Comment: That code looks awful.  I think you'd be way better off reading up on the algorithm and then implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "radix sort" is a tricky one.  There are actually two different sorts that work in a similar manner - MSB (most significant bit) radix and LSB (least significant bit) radix.  (You will sometimes see the B replaced with a D for digit).  Here are implementations of both.

MSB radix:

```
//arguments to sort an array:
//arr: array to be sorted
//begin: 0
//end: length of array
//bit: maximum number of bits required to represent numbers in arr
function sort(arr, begin, end, bit)
{
  var i, j, mask;
  i = begin;
  j = end;
  mask = 1 << bit;
  while(i < j)
  {
    while(i < j && !(arr[i] & mask))
    {
      ++i;
    }
    while(i < j && (arr[j - 1] & mask))
    {
      --j;
    }
    if(i < j)
    {
      j--;
      var tmp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = tmp;
      i++;
    }
  }
  if(bit && i > begin)
  {
    sort(arr, begin, i, bit - 1);
  }
  if(bit && i < end)
  {
    sort(arr, i, end, bit - 1);
  }
}
sort(arr, 0, arr.length, 32);  //Here I've assumed that the values in arr are integers that fit in 32 bits
```

LSB radix:

```
function insert(arr, i, j)
{
  tmp = arr[i];
  arr.splice(i, 1);
  arr.splice(j, 0, tmp);
}

//arguments to sort an array:
//arr: array to be sorted
function sort(arr)
{
  var bit, end, i, mask;
  bit = 0;
  while(true) 
  {
    mask = 1 << bit;
    i = 0;
    end = arr.length;
    while(i < end)
    {
      if(arr[i] & mask)
      {
        insert(arr, i, arr.length - 1);
        end--;
      }
      else
      {
        i++;
      }
    }
    bit++;
    if(end === arr.length)
    {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I pulled these algorithms off of http://visualsort.appspot.com/.  Then I compiled them to javascript at http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/, and wrote the insert method/reformatted for readability.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, thanks for the help. Two quick questions: (1) would you mind adding argument comments so that I know what values to pass, (2) which method is suppose to be faster, using LSD or MSD?

Comment: MSD is generally faster, but it is unstable, whereas LSD is a stable sort.

Comment: Why is MSD unstable? My use case is only integers

Comment: To clarify, stable, in the context of sorting algorithms, means that identical elements will stay in the same order as when they started.  MSD can change the order of identical elements.  This is only relevant when there is something else to the data.  For example, if you have objects representing people that are sorted alphabetically by name, and you LSD radix by birthday, each day with multiple people born on it will have the people sorted alphabetically.  MSD will not necessarily retain the alphabetical sorting by name.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided is no longer available but I hope for my implementation to be as lucid as possible for you or anybody  interested.

I'm implementing the version of radix sort introduced in CRLS 3rd ed section 8.2

Let's start by the pseudo-code:

[image: counting sort]

```
/**
 * @param k: the max of input, used to create a range for our buckets
 * @param exp: 1, 10, 100, 1000, ... used to calculate the nth digit
 */
Array.prototype.countingSort = function (k, exp) {
    /* eslint consistent-this:0 */
    /* self of course refers to this array */
    const self = this;

    /**
     * let's say the this[i] = 123, if exp is 100 returns 1, if exp 10 returns 2, if exp is 1 returns 3
     * @param i
     * @returns {*}
     */
    function index(i) {
        if (exp)
            return Math.floor(self[i] / exp) % 10;
        return i;
    }

    const LENGTH = this.length;

    /* create an array of zeroes */
    let C = Array.apply(null, new Array(k)).map(() => 0);
    let B = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        C[index(i)]++;

    for (let i = 1; i < k; i++)
        C[i] += C[i - 1];

    for (let i = LENGTH - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        B[--C[index(i)]] = this[i];
    }

    B.forEach((e, i) => {
        self[i] = e
    });
}
```

And that's the  only tricky part, the rest is very simple

```
Array.prototype.radixSort = function () {
    const MAX = Math.max.apply(null, this);

    /* let's say the max is 1926, we should only use exponents 1, 10, 100, 1000 */
    for (let exp = 1; MAX / exp > 1; exp *= 10) {
        this.countingSort(10, exp);
    }
}
```

Now here is a how you can test this method

```
let a = [589, 111, 777, 65, 124, 852, 345, 888, 553, 654, 549, 448, 222, 165];
a.radixSort()
console.log(a);
```

Finally, as mentionned in the book, this particular algorithm works only because counting-sort is an in-place sorting algorithm, which means that if two elements tie, their order of occurence in the input array is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

My version is more verbose, but executes very quickly for large datasets:

```
      var testArray = [ 331, 454, 230, 34, 343, 45, 59, 453, 345, 231, 9 ];

  function radixBucketSort (arr) {
    var idx1, idx2, idx3, len1, len2, radix, radixKey;
    var radices = {}, buckets = {}, num, curr;
    var currLen, radixStr, currBucket;

    len1 = arr.length;
    len2 = 10;  // radix sort uses ten buckets

    // find the relevant radices to process for efficiency        
    for (idx1 = 0;idx1 < len1;idx1++) {
      radices[arr[idx1].toString().length] = 0;
    }

    // loop for each radix. For each radix we put all the items
    // in buckets, and then pull them out of the buckets.
    for (radix in radices) {          
      // put each array item in a bucket based on its radix value
      len1 = arr.length;
      for (idx1 = 0;idx1 < len1;idx1++) {
        curr = arr[idx1];
        // item length is used to find its current radix value
        currLen = curr.toString().length;
        // only put the item in a radix bucket if the item
        // key is as long as the radix
        if (currLen >= radix) {
          // radix starts from beginning of key, so need to
          // adjust to get redix values from start of stringified key
          radixKey = curr.toString()[currLen - radix];
          // create the bucket if it does not already exist
          if (!buckets.hasOwnProperty(radixKey)) {
            buckets[radixKey] = [];
          }
          // put the array value in the bucket
          buckets[radixKey].push(curr);          
        } else {
          if (!buckets.hasOwnProperty('0')) {
            buckets['0'] = [];
          }
          buckets['0'].push(curr);          
        }
      }
      // for current radix, items are in buckets, now put them
      // back in the array based on their buckets
      // this index moves us through the array as we insert items
      idx1 = 0;
      // go through all the buckets
      for (idx2 = 0;idx2 < len2;idx2++) {
        // only process buckets with items
        if (buckets[idx2] != null) {
          currBucket = buckets[idx2];
          // insert all bucket items into array
          len1 = currBucket.length;
          for (idx3 = 0;idx3 < len1;idx3++) {
            arr[idx1++] = currBucket[idx3];
          }
        }
      }
      buckets = {};
    }
  }
  radixBucketSort(testArray);
  console.dir(testArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Radix Sort is a wonderful linear time sorting algorithm. Many fast implementations have been done for CPU and GPU. Here is one I translated from my C++ implementation into JavaScript. It compares with JavaScript built-in sort and is 5 to 50X faster for sorting arrays of unsigned integers

```
var extractDigit = function( a, bitMask, shiftRightAmount ) {
    var digit = (a & bitMask) >>> shiftRightAmount; // extract the digit we are sorting based on
    return digit;
}
// June 2017 Victor J. Duvanenko High Performance LSD Radix Sort for arrays of unsigned integers
function radixSortLSD(_input_array) {
    var numberOfBins = 256;
    var Log2ofPowerOfTwoRadix = 8;
    var _output_array = new Array(_input_array.length);
    var count = new Array(numberOfBins);
    var _output_array_has_result = false;

    var bitMask = 255;
    var shiftRightAmount = 0;

    var startOfBin = new Array( numberOfBins );
    var endOfBin   = new Array( numberOfBins );

    while( bitMask != 0 )    // end processing digits when all the mask bits have been processed and shifted out, leaving no bits set in the bitMask
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBins; i++ )
            count[ i ] = 0;
        for (var _current = 0; _current < _input_array.length; _current++ )    // Scan the array and count the number of times each digit value appears - i.e. size of each bin
            count[ extractDigit( _input_array[ _current ], bitMask, shiftRightAmount ) ]++;

        startOfBin[ 0 ] = endOfBin[ 0 ] = 0;
        for( var i = 1; i < numberOfBins; i++ )
            startOfBin[ i ] = endOfBin[ i ] = startOfBin[ i - 1 ] + count[ i - 1 ];
        for ( var _current = 0; _current < _input_array.length; _current++ )
            _output_array[ endOfBin[ extractDigit( _input_array[ _current ], bitMask, shiftRightAmount ) ]++ ] = _input_array[ _current ];

        bitMask <<= Log2ofPowerOfTwoRadix;
        shiftRightAmount += Log2ofPowerOfTwoRadix;
        _output_array_has_result = !_output_array_has_result;

        var tmp = _input_array, _input_array = _output_array, _output_array = tmp;    // swap input and output arrays
    }
    if ( _output_array_has_result )
        for ( var _current = 0; _current < _input_array.length; _current++ )    // copy from output array into the input array
            _input_array[ _current ] = _output_array[ _current ];

    return _input_array;
}
```

For more details about this implementation and performance comparisons [High Performance JavaScript Radix Sort LSD](https://duvanenko.tech.blog/2017/06/15/faster-sorting-in-javascript/)